# Google Map API v2 (meta-data not found)

Tags: android, google-maps

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="com.pmss"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.pmss.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.pmss.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_main" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.Register"
            android:label="@string/button_register"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.UserInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_info"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.Payment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_payment"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.TrackParcel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_track_parcel"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.TrackMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_track_map"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
        </activity>     
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.CheckCard"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_check_card"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.RequestService"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_request_service"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.MainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Login" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.StaffInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_staff_info"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.FulfillRequest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fulfill_request"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.OnlinePayment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_online_payment"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.CardPayment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_card_payment"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.CashPayment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cash_payment"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.Payment" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.Payment" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pmss.StaffTrackParcel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_staff_track_parcel"
            android:parentActivityName="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.pmss.StaffMainMenu" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_API_KEY" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is activity_track_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment  
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is TrackMap.class

```
public class TrackMap extends FragmentActivity{
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_map);

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }  
}
```

This is the logcat

```
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559): Process: com.pmss, PID: 18559
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pmss/com.pmss.TrackMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.pmss.TrackMap.onCreate(TrackMap.java:14)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    ... 11 more
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 1.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.B(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.A(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.gW(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
05-08 01:07:36.429: E/AndroidRuntime(18559):    ... 21 more
```

I have tried this coding on new project it can display the map, but this coding won't display the map as it seems like it forced closed my application. It keep says I don't have the meta data which is

`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

And I have put this in my AndroidManifest.xml, it just keep say it can't found my meta-data tag. I'll appreciate with all the help here thanks.

Comment: do you have the updated google play services

Comment: Yes, I have update my google play services in my SDK manager

Comment: You are missing `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in your manifest

Comment: @Lal: That is for Maps V1. The OP is using Maps V2.

Comment: Try moving your `<meta-data>` element to the bottom, after the `<activity>` elements, next to your other Maps V2 `<meta-data>` element.

Comment: I have tried this, it still have the same error and I update my AndroidMenifest.xml

Comment: Check your `R.java` file whether you have a value for `google_play_services_version` inside integer

Comment: `public static final int google_play_services_version = 0x7f080000` this is the number I have

Comment: Replace `@integer/google_play_services_version` with `0x7f080000` and check..

Comment: My logcat still have this problem it say found 2131230720 `05-08 01:37:51.009: E/AndroidRuntime(24081): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4323000 but found 2131230720.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
`

Comment: @Jiazzyuser remove google play services reference and again reference the same by importing to workspace if using eclipse

Comment: @Raghunandan you mean remove the google_play_service project from my workspace and then import it again?

Comment: Please Replace `@integer/google_play_services_version` with `4323000` and check

Comment: Also see this `google-play-services_lib --> res --> values --> version.xml` for the correct version of google play services

Comment: @Raghunandan I has tried that but it end up the same error,

Comment: @Lal after I change the version number to 4323000, the map able to load in my mobile applications already thanks

Comment: Its ok..I'll post this as the answer..Please mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `@integer/google_play_services_version` with `4323000`

see this

**google-play-services_lib --> res --> values --> version.xml**

for the correct version of your google play services

Comment: why should you hardcode? when this `@integer/google_play_services_version` should work. you will find the same in google play servies library project `version.xml` if you have the updated google play services

Comment: its not a good practice to hardcode..but still he wants the application to work na.. I was just telling him a solution..@Raghunandan

Comment: `@integer/google_play_services_version` should work. I don't see any reason or come across a situation where that does not work

Comment: Yes it should work in normal case..But here,it didnt work..That was why i came up with this idea..

Comment: I created new project it works with `@integer/google_play_services_version` while the on-going project didn't work as it seems

Comment: @Raghunandan I think I found the problem lies, ` <integer name="google_play_services_version">1</integer>`in my project-> res -> values -> intergers.xml.. The error said it found the interger is 1.

Comment: @Jiazzyuser are you sure you have the latest google play services. If so you should the updated version there

Comment: my SDK manager said my Google Play Services is the latest (Rev.16)

Answer (score 0):

project -> res -> values -> intergers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="google_play_services_version">1</integer>
</resources>
```

The values assigned here is 1. This does not match with my google play service version which is 4323000. What I did was change the value from 1 to 4323000. and it works well.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I didn't hardcode in the android:value in this meta-data tag.